# Really odd for loop behavior

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm comparing 2 integers in a loop which loops through an array which contains JSON objects. The JSON objects contain an ID and a Name. When I click on the close button of my window that window should disappear and the others should remain but what happens is that if I close the window with the highest ID all of them get close and if for example I close the fifth one the #1-5 gets closed but the higher IDs remain.

```
    ctrl.items = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Number one"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Number two"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Number three"
    }];

    ctrl.removeWindow = function(toBeRemovedId) {
        console.log("Called: " + toBeRemovedId);
        for (var i = ctrl.items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            console.log(ctrl.items[i].id + " " + toBeRemovedId);
            if(ctrl.items[i].id == toBeRemovedId) {
                ctrl.items.splice(ctrl.items[i], 1);
            }
        };
    }

    <div class="window show" id="item_window" ng-repeat="item in itemWindowCtrl.items">
        <hgroup>
            <h1>{{ item.name}}</h1>
            <button class="close" ><span class="fa fa-times fa-lg" ng-click="itemWindowCtrl.removeWindow(item.id)"></span></button>
        </hgroup>
        <section>
            <p>{{ item.id + " " + item.name }}</p>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance for any clues you might be able to bring me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array splice function takes the index, rather than the item to remove, so you should just be doing:

`ctrl.items.splice(i, 1);`

The looping is a bit unnecessary though.  Why don't you just pass through the item to be removed rather than looping through in descending id order to find matching, id?  For example:

`ng-click="itemWindowCtrl.removeWindow(item)"`

Then in your controller / directive:

`ctrl.items.splice(ctrl.items.indexOf(item), 1);`

Comment: Oh right, I completely forgot about that way of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change the for loop to get the index and then just remove that index

```
   var index = -1;
   for (var i = 0; i < ctrl.items.length; i++) {
        if(ctrl.items[i].id === toBeRemovedId) {
            index = i;
        }
    };
    ctrl.items.splice(index, 1);
```